# Kendo dropdownlist parse variables

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, kendo-ui

I got Order entity, where I can choose operator when I'm adding comment

My variables in OperatorViewModel:

```
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
```

OrderController:

```
        var operatorComment = operatorRepository.Get();
        var operatorCommentList = operatorComment.Select(opList => new OperatorViewModel
        {
            Id = opList.Id,
            FirstName = opList.FirstName
        })
        .ToList();

        ViewBag.AvailableOperatorComment = operatorCommentList;
```

Kendo column:

```
            columns.Bound(c => c.OperatorFirstName)
            .Title(T("Sales.Order.Operator"))
            .ClientTemplate($@"#= OperatorFirstName # #= OperatorLastName #")
            .EditorTemplateName("OperatorCommentList")
            .EditorViewData(new { AvailableOperator = ViewBag.AvailableOperatorComment });
```

OperatorCommentList template:

```
@model OperatorViewModel

@{
var orderOperatorCommentList = ViewData["AvailableOperator"] as 
List<OperatorViewModel>;
}

@(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m)
    .DataValueField(nameof(OperatorViewModel.Id))
    .DataTextField(nameof(OperatorViewModel.FirstName))
    .BindTo(orderOperatorCommentList)
)
```

And in OrderOperatorCommentViewModel list:

```
public List<SelectListItem> AvailableOperatorComment { get; set; }
```

Now how can I change dataTextField to parse FirstName and LastName? I want on list first name and lastname, but don't know how to do it

Comment: Could you add a NameDisplay property to your model and bind that to your drop down template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to achieve this in the client, probably best to use a template. Something like this should do it:

```
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m)
    .DataValueField(nameof(OperatorViewModel.Id))
    .DataTextField(nameof(OperatorViewModel.FirstName))
    .Template("#:data.FirstName# #:data.LastName#")
    .BindTo(orderOperatorCommentList)
)
```

See this [example](https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/dropdownlist/template) for more details.